# How do I set the parts of a string between a "." to different variables?

Tags: string, variables, batch-file, text

I was wondering how to set the characters before the first period to a variable called "Root", then the characters in between the second and third period to a variable called "Function" and set the characters after the second period to a variable named "Execute".

```
Set Input=Programs.Run.ABC.bat
```

In this case I would like:

```
Root = Programs
Function = Run
Execute = ABC.bat
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

Set Input=Programs.Run.ABC.bat

for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=." %%a in ('echo %Input%') do (
   echo Root = %%a
   echo Function = %%b
   echo Execute = %%c
)
```